# getting error 503 when using onepage checkout in magento saveShippingMethod

Tags: magento, onepage-checkout

i have installed the extention IWD onepage checkout but i can´t place an order.
Firebug shows in the console an error 503 when trying to save the shipping method.
And here the reporting of magento

```
a:5:{i:0;s:46:"Die angeforderte Zahlart ist nicht verfügbar.";i:1;s:2289:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82): Mage::throwException('Die angefordert...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php(218): Mage_Payment_Model_Info->getMethodInstance()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/Block/Directpost/Form.php(72): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->getMethodInstance()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Authorizenet_Block_Directpost_Form->setMethodInfo()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/JsonController.php(171): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/community/IWD/Opc/controllers/JsonController.php(484): IWD_Opc_JsonController->_getReviewHtml()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): IWD_Opc_JsonController->saveShippingMethodAction()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveShippingMet...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}";s:3:"url";s:32:"/onepage/json/saveShippingMethod";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:6:"german";}
```

in the error i see that the payment method is not available but it is available and shown in the checkout.
I have only one shipping method activated table rate_best way.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorize.net payment method adds a block to the checkout review for some reason, which causes any onepage checkouts to fail if they attempt to render that block before the payment method is selected. This occurs even if Authorize.net is not enabled.

You can remove the offending block from the checkout by adding this to your `local.xml`. (However, you should check that the Authorize.net payment method still works if you are using it. I was not using it, so I could safely remove its block).

```
<checkout_onepage_review>
    <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <remove name="payment.form.directpost" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_review>
```